# Performing Dunnett's Multiple Comparison Test in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have determined that the most applicable post-hoc statistical analysis following a one-way ANOVA of my data is Dunnett's test. I have performed this using R in the past, however I am now restricted to python due to the packages I have used to automate my workflow (automatic analysis of large data quantities).

I have found several packages (eg. sci-kit, tukeyHSD) that supply multiple different post-hoc tests however none of them include Dunnett's. For example I can easily perform a one-way ANOVA in scipy:

```
import scipy.stats as stats

# Made up data
a = [10, 12, 10, 14, 18] # Control
b = [15, 14, 18, 10, 38]
c = [20, 22, 23, 34, 20]
d = [50, 48, 42, 51, 51]

stats.f_oneway(a, b, c, d)

> F_onewayResult(statistic=26.92639734366354, pvalue=1.7207487532445122e-06)
```

However I want a multiple comparison analysis following this comparing to a single control group with normally distributed data (n~1000). I am aware of Rpy2, however I wish to perform this on a machine without using a docker. Any suggestions on capable packages?

(I am also a biologist with pretty basic scripting knowledge so there's a large possibility that I'm missing something basic here)

Comment: can't you just implement this --> https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/dunnetts-test/

Comment: It looks like is already implemented over. https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_chisquare_pairscontrol.html?highlight=dunnet

Comment: @TavoGLC Thank you! I wasn't able to find it because it's spelled wrong on the documentation page and I was quote searching......

Comment: Could someone post the answer to this question using statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_chisquare_pairscontrol referenced by @TavoGLC? It's not obvious to me how to convert the data in the a,b,c,d groups into the 'count' and 'nobs' parameters required for the test.

Comment: It seems that the link referenced by @TavoGLC is  chisquare test for **proportions** for pairwise comparisons with a control group, not for **means**  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just introduced this into SciPy. It will be available in SciPy 1.11: `scipy.stats.dunnett`

You can have a look at the development doc here: https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dunnett.html

Any feedback is welcomed. (We are adding CI and better str method as I write this.)

Comment: Very simple to implement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks it's moving in the good direction with the team @ statsmodels (https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/852), in the meantime we have to use R or do the maths with the tables published some years ago.